# Raw Text must be wrapped in an explicit <Text> component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Got an error on this small script. 
Removed everything, but still got the error on this simple example. 
Got the "a" in the console but then an error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text
} from 'react-native';

export default class AfishaAbout extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        console.log("a")
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Test</Text>
            </View>
        )
        console.log("b")
    }
}
```

BTW: I saw one guy on github proposed some modifications to the RN source code to display the line number of this kind of errors, but I can't find it now.

Comment: The listed code is might be not the one producing the error, since the 2nd console.log is unreachable. Check if you have prefixed with !! all string values used as flags {stringFlag && ...}.

Comment: @elmeister Thanks, yes, the b is unreachable, my fault. But this is the exact code, I don't have any string flags here.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @ShaneG "Raw Text must be wrapped in an explicit <Text> component"

Answer (score 0):

Spaces matter in React so its possible that here:

```
 <View>
   <Text>Test</Text>
 </View>
```

There is a space trailing somewhere. I would try changing it to the following:

```
 <View><Text>Test</Text></View>
```

Just to see if the spaces is the issue, and remove the console.logs incase also. Let me know if that helps!